# MAXIFS: how to get rid of error when there is no max (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the `MAXIFS` formula to find the max date if criteria are met. However, when the criteria are NOT met, it is giving a max date of 12/30/99.

How can I get this to be blank when the criteria are not met?

My formula: `=maxifs(B:B, A:A, "x", D:D, "cc", E:E, "denied")`

The issue: When `"denied"` is missing from column E, the result is `12/30/99`. How can I get it to be blank?

**EDIT: I realized the result is `12/30/99` because the cell format is `date`. 
Is there any way to get the MAXIFS formula to be blank when criteria are not met? Or is this a find/replace sort of thing?**

I can also use an array formula `=ArrayFormula(LARGE(IF((D:D="cc")*(E:E="denied"),B:B),1))`, but noticed the array doesn't auto-update when all criteria are met. When criteria are not met (ie column E doesn't have `denied`, then I get an error: `NUM`

---

I tried adding a script to run a find/replace onEdit (found this from another StackExchange Q&A, but it made all cells within my range the same date.

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("inquiries.app date.bonus");
  var range = ss.getRange("L2:O4");
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for (var i=0;i< formulas.length;i++) {
    if(typeof formulas[i] !== "undefined" && formulas[i] != ""){
      formulas[i][0] = formulas[i][0].replace(12/30/99, "");
      data[i][0] = formulas[i][0].toString();
    }
  }
 range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date())
}
```

---

This script worked but changed my cell format to automatic. Is there a way to make sure cells are formatted as `date`?

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("inquiries.app date.bonus");
  var range = ss.getRange("L2:O4");
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for (var i=0;i< formulas.length;i++) {
    if(typeof formulas[i] !== "undefined" && formulas[i] != ""){
      formulas[i][0] = formulas[i][0].replace(12/30/99, "");
      data[i][0] = formulas[i][0].toString();
    }
  }
 range.setValues(data).setNumberFormat("0");
}
```

---

I tried these formulas, but nothing happened. In fact, it removed the cell formulas and changed it to values.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (s.getName() !== 'inquiries.app date.bonus' || e.value !== '12/30/99') return;
    e.range.setValue(s.getRange('never')
        .getValue());
}`

and

`function replace(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("inquiries.app date.bonus");
  var range = ss.getRange("L2:O4");
  var vlst=range.getValues();
  var i,j,a,find,repl;
  find="12/30/99";
  repl="never";
  for (var i = 0; i < vlst.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vlst[i].length; j++) {
      a = vlst[i][j];
      if (a == find) vlst[i][j] = repl;
  }
}
range.setValues(vlst);
}
```

and

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("inquiries.app date.bonus");
  find="12/30/1999";
  repl1= "never";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("inquiries.app date.bonus");
  var range = ss.getRange("L2:P4");
  var vlst=range.getValues();
  var i,j,a,find,repl;
  repl= repl1;
  for (i in vlst) {
    for (j in vlst[i]) {
      a=vlst[i][j];
      if (a==find) vlst[i][j]=repl;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(vlst);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can wrap it into **`IFERROR()`** to set custom **#NUM!** (in your case: if `#NUM!` then blank)

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(LARGE(IF((D:D="cc")*(E:E="denied"),B:B),1)),)
```

Comment: you're the best! this worked perfectly :) THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAXIFS(B:B, A:A, "x", D:D, "email", E:E, "denied")
```

this one works as well if you are willing to play with **Conditional formatting** in this way:

[image]

Comment: didn't work for me, even though the cells were formatted as a date. not sure why. but your 2nd answer worked like a dream. thank you!